# Providing sudo to another user

Tags: linux, sudo

I want to give sudo access to test user to switch to test2 sudo command in linux. But the test user should not go to root acccount.

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /etc/sudoers - add the test ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/bin/sudo /bin/su - test2

This worked

Answer (score 0):

Use sudoers file. It is analog for macos, but in linux is same. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82438/allow-sudo-to-another-user-without-password